# Discord.py-Rewrite Cycle through statuses using background tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

### My Goal

Hello, I want my bot to cycle through 3 prefixes, The prefix for the bot, The amount of servers its in, and another message of my choosing. I use the `@bot.command`/`@bot` thing, so the example in the FaQ in the readthedocs website doesn't help me. What i tried didn't work, and i also do not know how to get the number of servers the bot is in.

### What I tried

```
async def my_background_task(self):
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="message"))
    await asyncio.sleep(7)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="PREFIX: CF>"))
    await asyncio.sleep(7)



@bot.event
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Bot is online and ready.')
    self.bg_task = self.loop.create_task(self.my_background_task())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution has been tested:

```
prefixes = [lambda: 'prefix1', lambda: 'prefix2', lambda: str(len(bot.guilds))]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefixes[0]())

async def my_background_task():
    prefix_num = 0
    while True:

        prefix = prefixes[prefix_num]()
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=prefix))
        bot.command_prefix = prefix

        # increase the current prefix - if it's reached the length of the prefix list, set it back to 0
        prefix_num = (prefix_num + 1) % len(prefixes)

        await asyncio.sleep(7)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
```

First of all, your background task and on_ready function shouldn't have any `self` in them. Also, your background task has to have a while loop inside of it, otherwise, it will only run once.

This code utilizes anonymous lambda functions because it allows the bot to be added to a different server and adjust the prefix when that happens. When it comes time to change the prefix, one of the functions is called, returning a string.

I would also recommend looking at the [API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html) because it is very helpful.